# select statement calculated column issue with sums and groups

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, sum

I am trying to do a seemingly basic select statement but can't get the syntax correct for the where clause.

```
select 
    T1.CUSTNMBR [Customer Number],
    T1.APFRDCTY [Doc Type],
    sum(T1.APPTOAMT) as [Apply to Amount],
    T1.APFRDCNM [Apply From Doc No],
    T2.ORTRXAMT [Doc Amount],
    T2.CURTRXAM [Unapplied Amount]
from 
(
    select 
        CUSTNMBR, 
        APFRDCNM, 
        APFRDCTY, 
        APPTOAMT
    from GPSTJ..RM30201
    union 
    select 
        CUSTNMBR as CUSTNMBR, 
        APFRDCNM as APFRDCNM,
        APFRDCTY as APFRDCTY,
        APPTOAMT as APPTOAMT    
    from GPSTJ..RM20201
) T1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    select 
        CUSTNMBR, 
        DOCNUMBR, 
        DOCDATE, 
        RMDTYPAL, 
        ORTRXAMT, 
        CURTRXAM     
    from GPSTJ..RM20101
    union
    select
        CUSTNMBR as CUSTNMBR, 
        DOCNUMBR as DOCNUMBR, 
        DOCDATE as  DOCDATE, 
        RMDTYPAL as RMDTYPAL, 
        ORTRXAMT as ORTRXAMT, 
        CURTRXAM as CURTRXAM 
    from GPSTJ..RM30101
) T2 on T1.CUSTNMBR = T2.CUSTNMBR and T1.APFRDCNM = T2.DOCNUMBR

where (sum(T1.APPTOAMT) - T2.ORTRXAMT) <> T2.CURTRXAM

group by
T1.CUSTNMBR, T1.APFRDCTY, T1.APFRDCNM, T2.ORTRXAMT, T2.CURTRXAM
```

The query runs fine without the where clause however there are far too many results. I'm basically trying to subtract a grouped field (T2.ORTRXAMT) from a sum, sum(T1.APPTOAMT) but I can't get the syntax right, it just doesn't work and there's no clue in the error message.

Comment: OK So I was running this through excel with a data connection with no error message, but I ran it through SSMS and was given this -

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

I am reading up on solutions to this now but any help in the meantime would be good. Thankyou

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` clause when filtering on aggregates or groups

```
SELECT
    T1.CUSTNMBR AS [Customer Number],
    T1.APFRDCTY AS [Doc Type],
    SUM(T1.APPTOAMT) AS [Apply to Amount],
    T1.APFRDCNM AS [Apply From Doc No],
    T2.ORTRXAMT AS [Doc Amount],
    T2.CURTRXAM AS [Unapplied Amount]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CUSTNMBR, APFRDCNM, APFRDCTY, APPTOAMT
    FROM GPSTJ..RM30201
    UNION
    SELECT
        CUSTNMBR AS CUSTNMBR, 
        APFRDCNM AS APFRDCNM,
        APFRDCTY AS APFRDCTY,
        APPTOAMT AS APPTOAMT    
    FROM GPSTJ..RM20201
)T1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        CUSTNMBR, DOCNUMBR, DOCDATE, RMDTYPAL, ORTRXAMT, CURTRXAM
    FROM GPSTJ..RM20101
    UNION
    SELECT
        CUSTNMBR AS CUSTNMBR, 
        DOCNUMBR AS DOCNUMBR, 
        DOCDATE AS DOCDATE, 
        RMDTYPAL AS RMDTYPAL, 
        ORTRXAMT AS ORTRXAMT, 
        CURTRXAM AS CURTRXAM 
    FROM GPSTJ..RM30101
) T2 
    ON T1.CUSTNMBR = T2.CUSTNMBR
    AND T1.APFRDCNM = T2.DOCNUMBR
GROUP BY
    T1.CUSTNMBR, T1.APFRDCTY, T1.APFRDCNM, T2.ORTRXAMT, T2.CURTRXAM
HAVING
    (SUM(T1.APPTOAMT) - T2.ORTRXAMT) <> T2.CURTRXAM
```